# Iterating over a vector does not update the objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm learning C++ and have come to a bit of a halt. I'm trying to iterate over a vector with a range-based for loop and update a property on each of the objects that belong to it. The loop is inside of an update function. The first time it fires, it works fine; I can see the property gets updated on each member of the vector. However, the next time the for loop is initiated, it's still updating the original data, as if the previous run did not actually update the source values. Is my range declaration configured correctly? Pointers are still a bit of a mystery to me. In general I'd be very thankful for any help!

```
for (Point &point : points)
    {
        Vector3 position = point.position;

        if (position != destination)
        {
            Vector3 move = Vector3::Zero;
            
            if (position.x > destination.x)
                move.x -= 1.0;

            if (position.x < destination.x)
                move.x += 1.0;

            if (position.y > destination.y)
                move.y -= 1.0;

            if (position.y < destination.y)
                move.y += 1.0;

            if (position.z > destination.z)
                move.z -= 1.0;

            if (position.z < destination.z)
                move.z += 1.0;

            position += move;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Vector3 position = point.position;` looks an awful lot like making a copy of something.

Comment: Thank you! Thought that worked differently somehow. That worked. Obviously. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Vector3 position = point.position;` makes a *copy* of `point.position`.  The following code then updates this copy, which in turn is thrown away when it goes out of scope at the end of the `if` statement.

The solution is simple enough - use a reference instead: `Vector3 &position = point.position;`.  The rest of the code can be left as-is.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying `position`, but not `point.position`, because `position` is a copy of `point.position`.

If you instead want to make `position` a reference to `point.position`, then you must change the line

`Vector3 position = point.position;`

to

`Vector3 &position = point.position;`

That way, modifying `position` will also modify `point.position`.